# PHP proc_open - connect to mysqldump works, but not to mysql

Tags: php, mysql, connection, background-process

I have the problem, that mysql does not allow me to connect in one case, but in another one it does.

i am using `proc_open` to connect to mysql via the `mysqldump` command and pass the password through the pipe.

interestingly this call works as expected, whereas the other one doesn't....

```
$command = "mysqldump --no-data -h 127.0.0.1 -u root -p dbname > /var/www/html/dump.sql"
$process = proc_open($command, [
    0 => ["pipe", "r"],
    1 => ["pipe", "w"],
    2 => ["pipe", "w"]
], $pipes);

if (is_resource($process))
{
    fwrite($pipes[0], $this->password);
    fclose($pipes[0]);
    ...
```

the next call does not work - `ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)`.

i really don't understand that, because the connection establishment should be the same for `mysql` and `mysqldump`. i can assure, that the password is correct, because it is fetched from a config file and I already checked by debugging.

if i execute the same command directly on shell, i don't have a problem to connect by entering the password. but through php it does not work.

```
$command = "mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -u root -p -D dbname < /var/www/html/dump.sql"
$process = proc_open($command, [
    0 => ["pipe", "r"],
    1 => ["pipe", "w"],
    2 => ["pipe", "w"]
], $pipes);

if (is_resource($process))
{
    fwrite($pipes[0], $this->password);
    fclose($pipes[0]);
    ...
```

Comment: This particular example does not make much sense. i adapted filenames and paths to simplify the examples. in real life the commands make much more sense :)

Comment: You mean in the real code your are using full paths to the mysqldump and mysql programs?

Comment: Verifiy the file group and acces rights off `/var/www/html/dump.sql` with `ls -l` and if it's accesable with the program mysql.

Comment: no, `mysql` & `mysqldump` are in PATH. i mean the sql files. those are only there to get a picture what i am trying to do. but the original files that are used have proper paths/rights. the sql files do not have something to do with my problem.